Create Vector Store on OpenAI with curl, and Upload 2 PDfs to it with curl
I learned that OpenAI has integrated vector store now so I do not need an external vector database. So my question is if it is all possible with just API requests using curl
Can I create a vector store with curl .
and then upload 2 PDFs to vector with just a curl command.
And then I can ask quesiton also just with a curl.
i want to test it out only using API requests, and would be immensely amazing, if its possible ?

OpenAI documentation mention the vector DBS https://platform.openai.com/docs/assistants/tools/file-search/vector-stores
It give the instruction to

Creating vector stores and adding files
Attaching vector stores
Customizing File Search settings

And the API calls that you need
from openai import OpenAI
 
client = OpenAI()
 
assistant = client.beta.assistants.create(
  name="Financial Analyst Assistant",
  instructions="You are an expert financial analyst. Use you knowledge base to answer questions about audited financial statements.",
  model="gpt-4o",
  tools=[{"type": "file_search"}],
)


OP is asking for the curl request, not using the Python library.
